# sql - concatenating case statements

Tags: sql, concatenation, case

I want to do something similar to:

```
SELECT
   ('['+twt.dept+']' + 
     CASE WHEN twt.typ <> 'EMPTY' AND twt.typ > '' THEN '-['+twt.typ+']' END
     + CASE WHEN twt.subtyp_1 <> 'EMPTY' AND twt.subtyp_1 > '' THEN '-['+twt.subtyp_1+']' END
     + CASE WHEN twt.subtyp_2 <> 'EMPTY' AND twt.subtyp_2 > '' THEN '-['+twt.subtyp_2+']' END
     + CASE WHEN twt.subtyp_3 <> 'EMPTY' AND twt.subtyp_3 > '' THEN '-['+twt.subtyp_3+']' END) AS category
FROM table1 AS tb1
JOIN table2 AS twt ON (tb1.id = twt.id)
```

I know I can use coalesce or using stacking cases, but is their anyways to use simpler looking syntax like I have here to achieve this (especially without having a monster case statement for the 5th case)?

PS category is coming back as empty, while i have verified that atleast two of the field above do contain values.

I am hoping to get something like [shoes]-[sandals]-[pancakes]-[cinnamon bun]

Comment: What RDBMS and version? Also you have no `ELSE` in your `CASE` expressions which means they can return `NULL`. And concatenating `NULL` yields `NULL`. Is this the intention?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can make your query shorter. You even use separate fields. Technically you could use some functions that do the `CASE WHEN` work, but I don't think the gain is enough.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckAndAdd(@str VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(255) AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE WHEN @str <> 'EMPTY' AND @str <> '' THEN '-['+@str+']' ELSE '' END
END
```

**Note that if a `CASE` fails and it doesn't have an `ELSE` it returns `NULL`, and in SQL `'Hello' + NULL = NULL`**

Simple test:

```
SELECT 'Hello ' + CASE WHEN 1 = 0 THEN 'None' END + ' World'
```

Correct test:

```
SELECT 'Hello ' + CASE WHEN 1 = 0 THEN 'None' ELSE '' END + ' World'
```

Comment: Sorry i need to be more clear sometimes. This isnt working. Im only getting an empty field. My guess is that the alias is only being assigned to the last case statement.

Comment: Read the bold sentence :-)

Comment: Thankyou very much, this would have driven me insane.